# Checkbox ajax php, передача 1 переменной в обработку

Tags: ajax

Подскажите как сделать? Есть 1 чакбокс, как при выборе/снятии чекбокса сразу отправлять запрос в базу без обновления страницы и без дополнительной кнопки сабмит и нужно передавать обработчику 1 переменную id.

Comment: Примеров в гугле масса. Пожалуйста постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Посмотрите примеры в гугле, почитайте, что такое ajax и как он работает, виды событий ajax, запросы ajax и напишите что именно Вам непонятно как сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В файле test.php проверяете `$_POST["type"]` и обновляете данные в базе данных.

```js
$("#checkbox").on("click", function() {
  var type = $("#checkbox").is(":checked") ? 'yes' : 'no';
  $.ajax({
    url: 'test.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      type: type
    },
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      alert('Запрос выполнен');
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="yes">
<label>тест</label>
```

Comment: подскажи, если мне нужно передать переменную id по выбору чекбокса как это сделать ?

Comment: @МаксимС если нужно передать id стороннего  элемента, то 
`var id = $("#element").attr("id");`
и
`data: {
      type: type, id:id
    }`

Comment: спасибо за помощь.